# Hide an HTML banner from preview of email on a mobile device

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have an HTML banner that is being applied to emails that come in to our environment from an external sender.  After testing, it was revealed that the banner blocks a person from previewing a received email on the mobile device.  I have zero knowledge of HTML or CSS.  What I have is from piecing together from bits here and there.  The current articles I am reading are telling me to use the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.mobileHide { display: inline;}
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px){  .mobileHide { display: none;}}
</style>
```

I've altered my HTML to this:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
.mobileHide { display: inline;}
/* Smartphone Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px){  .mobileHide { display: none;}}
</style></head><body><div class="mobileHide"><table style="border: 1px 
solid black;border-collapse: collapse">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#ffac59">
<td>
<small>CAUTION: This is a test.</small>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table><h1></h1>
<br />
<mc type="body">

</div></body></html>
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, what *specifically* do you mean by "preview an email"? Do you mean that the email's [preview text](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support) shows header gibberish instead of the preview of the body text that you want it to?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Yes sir, that is correct.  When I open the Outlook mobile app and view my Inbox I can see all my emails and I should also see the first line of text from each one.  Instead, the stationary banner is displayed.

Comment: Hi Tar Heel, if you feel your question has been answered, please don't forget to mark one of the answers as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate so we can further help! Thanks!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Hey Max, all of the comments here have definitely been helpful.  But, I'm still not able to produce the results that I need.  I actually was just able to produce the EXACT opposite of what I want.  I see the header in the preview text, but when I look at the email in full, I cannot see the header at all.  Now, if I can just find a way to swap that around and keep the real body of the email intact.  I had a thought about maybe trying to hide the first X amount of characters from the preview since the header will always remain the same number of characters.

Comment: Have you tried putting together the email html in the following order from top to bottom? 1: hidden preview text hack div from my answer (with the first sentence of the email's body inside as preview text). 2: Your custom header. 3: The original email's code.

Comment: @TarHeel just add about 140 characters of space if you dont want to use preview text and want to hide anything else being shown as preview text. Also from you above code (not updated i take it) is needs a lot of more than code on the div. If you add any element inside the div, you will need to hide them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some desktop email clients also show email preview text, so any solution that removes the header only on mobile clients will leave desktop clients with the same problem you are trying to solve. Instead of targeting mobile clients, it makes more sense to work with the preview text directly.

To get custom preview text on your email, it has to be the first text that appears in your email's `body` section, even before your header.

[From litmus.com](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support):

> Preview text is pulled from the first few lines of text found within an email.

So what's happening is that the email client is reading the first few lines of your email to determine what to show as the preview text, but since your header is first, the email's preview text is the gibberish from the header section instead of the marketing speak that you want it to be. The parsing of the email preview as far as I can tell is unaffected by CSS styling such as `display: none`, though I could be wrong about that.

What Litmus recommends you do is to add an extra, hidden element before your email header (right after the opening `body` tag) that contains the preview text that you want to show in the email client. You'll want to use this code:

```
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#333333;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;">
  Insert preview text here.            
</div>
```

It's not pretty, but email HTML itself is not pretty. What this does is it makes a hidden element at the top of your email that the client will show as preview text, but that won't actually show to the end user when they open up the email.

In your situation, you might want to pull this preview text programmatically from the incoming email, then apply this element before applying the header.

Does this constitute spam or misleading behavior? Does it hurt your deliverability? Litmus says that it's fine in their experience:

> Using hacks like this to hide content occasionally brings up concerns about deliverability. Our experience has been that, used sparingly and alongside an otherwise clean sending reputation, this works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I can see is a typo in your style attribute:

```
<div class="”mobileHide”">
```

...has two double-quotes. It should be this:

```
<div class="mobileHide">
```

Comment: Thanks.  I corrected that and I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: @TarHeel, are you sure? I tried your code after the update and it works for me.

Comment: @Tibbelit HTML emails are fickle. It could be that the CSS works great in a browser but not the email client that Tar Heel is testing on.

Comment: @Tibbelit Yeah, I made the changes.  I even saw that the "text/css" had double quotes as well and corrected that.  We use Mimecast to filter all incoming mail and it has a policy that applies the HTML as a piece of stationary at the top of the emails.  When I send a test to myself that stationary is still visible and blocking the preview.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, lazy reading from me - my bad, thanks for polite note! :)